# Install differnet Frameworks in docker container

Tags: c#, windows, docker, visual-studio, cognex

I like to use the **Cognex VisionPRO Framework** in a docker container.
So Visual Studio 2017 (C#) will run on my Windows 10 machine and the framework should run in a docker container.

- This is an image recognition framework which contains some libs, a
  service for a license dongle and a camera driver. It installs an
  optional GUI as well.
- I like to install it into a docker container, because this framework
  exist in two versions and you can not have both on the same PC.
- Silent installation is possible, but I am not sure if it is possible
  that the docker container can recognize USB Dongles for example.

I do not understand how docker is working in detail.
I understand that docker container can host some server stuff. But does it make sense to install a framework?

Answer (score 1):

VisionPro has utility which called "VisionPro Application Wizard". This utility is able to create C# application for you based on vpp file provided. The cognex display along with other features embedded(docked) into API . 
You should be able to use the second instance of VisionPro as well with same dongle.